# SQLite use of autoincrement in a small table

Tags: sqlite

SQLite recommends to refrain from using AUTOINCREMENT:

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.

Now, I have a small table that:
1. Will have about 100-150 rows
2. User will add new rows to it very rarely, possibly a few new rows once in a year or two.

Once of table's columns is "id", and I want to use AUTOINCREMENT for "id" as a simple and short way to ensure that deleted ID's cannot be reused. Using AUTOINCREMENT is the fastest way to ensure this, however the quote says I should refrain using it.

The question: in my case, can I use AUTOINCREMENT or should I avoid using it **at all costs**? The table will be small and write requests to said table are expected to be **extremely rare**, so I doubt it will "impose extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation is *not* "Never, ever use this, and we have no idea why we even allow it." It's simply a statement that it has non-trivial *costs*, and therefore it should only be used when needed.

If you need it, then you *need* it.

Comment: Fair enough, the thing is that I can manage without using it, but I'm not sure if I should. I my case it's like this:
**Pros**: I need a way to ensure deleted "id's" cannot be reused and autoincrement is the easiest and fastest way to do so. ///
**Cons**: SQLite recoomends to avoid autoincrement.
I can avoid using it, it's not like autoincrement is the absolute must in my case. But it IS the simplest way to solve my problem. Thus I was wondering whether I should use it or avoid using at all costs if it's not an absolute must to use it.

Comment: I think it should depend on how frequently I'm writing to the table with autoincrement value, right? Like, if I'm writing 20 times a minute, autoincrement will lead to extensive usage of CPU, disk space etc, but if I'm writing 15 rows once in 2 years, it should not really matter, am I right?

Comment: @ZRK: This seems like a pretty simple thing to profile. Make a table with AUTOINCREMENT. Add a bunch of stuff to it. Do the same, but without AUTOINCREMENT. Time them both and compare the result.

Comment: Good idea, I will try it now and compare the results! Thank you

Comment: @ZRK, I'd go ahead and use it for your case. Your table will remain small and inserts won't be used often. I've used autoincrement on SQLite tables with multiple inserts per day and much larger row counts than you'll have, and I didn't have any problems. Trying to find a way around not reusing a previously deleted id, I think you'd end up encountering a higher cost than using autoincrement  in SQLite.

Comment: @Poosh Yeah, that's what I was thinking too. That quote about avoiding using autoincrement and its high cost got me confused.

Comment: You should note, though, that even *without* the AUTOINCREMENT keyword, you would have to reach 9223372036854775807 insertions before a rowid would be reused (see http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).  Are you *really* worried about reaching that number in your application?